# How to extract the related fields for base, version and others from this url?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have a url

```
http://example.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=17f88c4&f=fir&t_i=article_25&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.firstpost.com%2Fsports%2Fkotla-test-22.html%09&t_e=Kotla%20Test20struggle&t_d=Kotla%20Test20struggle&t_t=Kotla%20Test20struggle&s_o=default
```

The queries are
base, version, f, t_i, t_u, t_e, t_d, t_t, s_o

Constraints:

1. base, version, f are necessary.
2. Others t_i, t_u, t_e, t_d, t_d, s_o are optional i.e some may appear sometimes, sometimes not.

I need to find the correct regular expression. Learned about them and came up with this

```
r'^embed/comments/?base=(\w+)&version=(\w+)&f=\w+&t_i=\w+&t_u=.+&t_e=.+&t_d=.+&t_t=.+&s_o=\w+'
```

I am using django, so in urls.py ,the above should match and it does.

Q.0. How to extract the related fields for base, version and others? With the constraints what should be the regex modified to?

For example to save forum , below regex is used. I searched for more than two hours but could not find what `?P<forum>` functionality is

Q.1. What does `?P<forum>` mean?

```
r'^forum/(?P<forum>.+)/$'
```

P.S. I am a newbie to regex, please bear with me and explain in simpler terms. Thank you so much

Comment: `?P<forum>` inside brackets is naming group, if that group is matched, you can refer to it as `g<forum>` or `m.group('forum)'` see [python re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q.0** : They are query parameter then you don't have to put them in your url regex. You should test if some query parameters are missing in your view.

Here is a complete example :

in `urls.py` file, use this regex :

```python
url(r'embed/comments/', views.your_view),
```

and then in your `views.py` file:

```python
def your_view(request):
    # get your query params like this
    base = request.GET.get('base')
    version = request.GET.get('version')
    f = request.GET.get('f')
    # then test if some parameter are missing
    if base and version and f:
        # do what you want
```

**Q.1** : it's a named group. In django, this syntax will give your the ability to  get this parameter in your view.

**E.g** :
If a user reach `forum/hello-n00b` then  in your view

```python
def example(request, forum):
    # forum is equals to 'hello-n00b'
```

Comment: Gave two upvotes for ya'. Thank you so much. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Using naming groups, I would make it like this:

```
anyChar = "[^&]" # pattern to match any character inside url
necessary = ['base', 'version', 'f'] # list of necessary segments
others = ['t_i', 't_u', 't_e', 't_d', 't_d', 's_o'] # list of other allowed segments
pattern = "^embed/comments/\?" # start of pattern

# wrap all necessary to naming groups
necessaryPatterns = ["(?P<" + name + ">" + name + "=" + anyChar + "+)" for name in necessary]
# wrap all others into naming groups
othersPatterns = ["(?P<" + name + ">" + name + "=" + anyChar + "+)" for name in othersPatterns]


pattern += "&".join(necessaryPatterns) # append to pattern all necessary separated by "&" sign
pattern += "(?:&" # start optional segments with nom-matching group
pattern += ")?(?:&".join(othersPatterns) # append all others with closing-opening non-matching group marked as optional
pattern += ")?$" # end with $ to match end of string

regex = re.compile(pattern) # compile pattern
url = "your_super_long_url" # your url to match
match = re.match(pattern, url) # run match operation
if matchObj: # check if it matched
    base = match.group('base') # access matched named groups easily 
    version = match.group('version')
    ....
```

The example might contain errors, but it shall give you the basic idea. The names for segments shall be written as constants and wrapping names into naming group could be done by function, but my current skills of Python does not allow me to write full class in reasonable time.